# Non-removable MDM client app in Android

Tags: android, mdm

Are there any methods by which we can make an MDM client app in Android non-removable? Currently, if we remove the MDM app administration, we can simply uninstall the app.

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you found any solutions?

Comment: No, I didn't found a solution yet. But some applock apps do this by greying out Uninstall and Disable buttons. Wondering how.

Comment: Can you share those App names? I tried AppLock but I managed to uninstall it on Android 7.0

Answer (score 0):

If your company uses Samsung devices take a look at Enterprise Mobile Management (EMM) by Samsung.

Once enrolled there is no way to delete or disable (everything up to admin)

https://www.samsungknox.com/en/solutions/knox-premium

Update: https://www.samsungknox.com/en/solutions/it-solutions/knox-manage

Now product named Knox Manage